# JSON Parse Javascript Issues

Tags: javascript, json

I am using the following to load a local txt file to convert it, the code is directly from W3c schools but the page loads nothing on screen and I have no errors on page or in the inspector. It wont work on MAMP or webserver. I am trying to learn vanilla JS so I don't want to use a library or jquery.

```
<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "array.txt";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            myFunction(myArr);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function myFunction(arr) {
        var out = "";
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' +
                arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
        }
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: _the code is directly from W3c schools..._ No wonder it doesn't work :) Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) as your first source for learning

Comment: Check the network panel - does the request actually get made to begin with, and if so, what does the server answer it with (status code)?

Comment: The ability of reading local files with AJAX was removed for a few years ago from the browsers it was possible (Firefox, only?), in most of the browsers it was never possible.

Comment: Did you run it from a local webserver (URL is http://localhost) or directly from file (URL is file://path/to/html/file.html)?

Comment: CBroe - The status shows as 'finished' opposed to 200, which makes sense as the code is looking for a 200 status to start the process. However, switching to the URL source for data: https://www.w3schools.com/js/myTutorials.txt I get a 200 status but still no rending of the data. Any advice?

Comment: Jamie Phan - I have run the code from my local server and webserver, I have also hosted the text file locally and from a url.

Comment: The file has to be saved in a  MAMP server folder when running a local server page, a page loaded from a web server can't read local files at all with AJAX. You can load files from user's local system using [FileReader Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help everyone, the issue was a clash with another function running on the page and the lack of 200 response from the local file.